# How to stop functions 'resetting' after calling a function. Python

Tags: python

When call back to the main function, after entering in the movie names and prices, I want the movieNameList, moviePriceList and x to be returned to main. But of course the variable I set in the main function will reset all this. How can I prevent this?

```
def addMovie(movieNameList, moviePriceList, x):
    movieNameList.append(input("Name of Movie\n>>> "))
    moviePriceList.append(input("How much would you like to rent " + movieNameList[x] + " for? ($6-12 NZD)\n>>> "))
    moviePriceList[x] = int(moviePriceList[x])
    while moviePriceList[x] >= 13 and moviePriceList[x] <= 5:
        moviePriceList.pop
        print("Invalid Input")
        moviePriceList.append(input("How much would you like to rent " + movieNameList[x] + " for? ($6-12 NZD)\n>>> "))
    x += 1
    print(str(x))
    print(movieNameList)
    print(moviePriceList)
    menu = input("Input '1' to add another movie to the store\n" \
                 + "Input '2' to return to the menu")
    if menu == "1":
        movieNameList, moviePriceList, x = addMovie(movieNameList, moviePriceList, x)
    if menu == "2":
        main()
        return movieNameList, moviePriceList, x

def main(movieNameList, movieRentalList, x):
    movieNameList = []
    moviePriceList = []
    x = 0
    menu = input("Input '1' to add a movie to the store\n" \
                 + "Input '2' to veiw the list of movies\n" \
                 + "input '3' to end the programme\n" \
                 + ">>> ")
    if menu == "1":
        movieNameList, moviePriceList, x = addMovie(movieNameList, moviePriceList, x)

main()
```

I cannot think of a way to fix this without resetting the variables and lists.

Comment: You need to move your two movie lists outside of the `main` function, otherwise you keep on resetting them to empty again. Put them just above your `main()` function call - you can still access them from within your functions. Also, no need to have them as arguments in your `main` function.

Comment: Currently, your `main` function is both the literal main function of the program **and** the main *menu* function. Simply split the logic. Add another function to be the main program function which resets the variables, and a **main menu** function to present the menu

Comment: You can also look at the `self` in python classes, to reference the variables without parsing them to the functions as you can then just use `self.movieNameList`. Move the movie lists thus outside of the main function into a class.

Answer (score 0):

You could use global variables to prevent them from being reset:

```
movieNameList = []
moviePriceList = []
x = 0

def addMovie():
    global movieNameList, moviePriceList, x
    movieNameList.append(input("Name of Movie\n>>> "))
    moviePriceList.append(input("How much would you like to rent " + movieNameList[x] + " for? ($6-12 NZD)\n>>> "))
    moviePriceList[x] = int(moviePriceList[x])
    while moviePriceList[x] >= 13 or moviePriceList[x] <= 5:
        print("Invalid Input")
        moviePriceList[x] = int(input("How much would you like to rent " + movieNameList[x] + " for? ($6-12 NZD)\n>>> "))
    x += 1
    print(str(x))
    print(movieNameList)
    print(moviePriceList)
    menu = input("Input '1' to add another movie to the store\n"
                 + "Input '2' to return to the menu\n"
                 + ">>> ")
    if menu == "1":
        addMovie()

def main():
    global movieNameList, moviePriceList, x
    menu = input("Input '1' to add a movie to the store\n"
                 + "Input '2' to view the list of movies\n"
                 + "Input '3' to end the program\n"
                 + ">>> ")
    if menu == "1":
        addMovie()
    elif menu == "2":
        print(movieNameList)
        print(moviePriceList)
    elif menu == "3":
        return

main()
```

Also I added the functionality to return from the function if the input was 3.

Answer (score 0):

If you put the two empty lists, `movieNameList = []` and `moviePriceList = []` and set `x` to 0 inside your function, then every time `main()` is called, the variables will be reset. To solve that, you should define your variables and lists outside the function. Modified code:

```
#Define the variables outside the function
movieNameList = []
moviePriceList = []
x = 0

def addMovie():
    global movieNameList, moviePriceList, x
    movieNameList.append(input("Name of Movie\n>>> "))
    moviePriceList.append(input("How much would you like to rent " + movieNameList[x] + " for? ($6-12 NZD)\n>>> "))
    moviePriceList[x] = int(moviePriceList[x])
    while moviePriceList[x] >= 13 and moviePriceList[x] <= 5:
        moviePriceList.pop
        print("Invalid Input")
        moviePriceList.append(input("How much would you like to rent " + movieNameList[x] + " for? ($6-12 NZD)\n>>> "))
    x += 1
    print(str(x))
    print(movieNameList)
    print(moviePriceList)
    menu = input("Input '1' to add another movie to the store\n" \
                 + "Input '2' to return to the menu")
    if menu == "1":
        movieNameList, moviePriceList, x = addMovie(movieNameList, moviePriceList, x)
    if menu == "2":
        main()
        return movieNameList, moviePriceList, x

def main():
    global movieNameList, movieRentalList, x
    menu = input("Input '1' to add a movie to the store\n" \
                 + "Input '2' to veiw the list of movies\n" \
                 + "input '3' to end the programme\n" \
                 + ">>> ")
    if menu == "1":
        movieNameList, moviePriceList, x = addMovie(movieNameList, moviePriceList, x)

main()
```

If you define the variables outside the function, then they will become global variables by default. So, you can access them from within the functions. Inside your function, you don't need add parameters.